# FineUploader says "No files were uploaded"

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I am in the first stages of using/trying fineuploader, so I tried to build an example following the tutorial and I am unable to get it to work. It is always just retrying and in the log returning "No files were uploaded" that means $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] was not set.

I used the html like the one on the page in the section "Putting it together" (also downloaded the needed css, js and linked it to my php code): http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/02-setting_options.html
My php server code is exactly the one from https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php/traditional.

Can somebody please help me?

EDIT:
I am actually trying in on two different servers now, there are 2 different errors in the **browser console** :
For built-in php server:

```
"[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] Retrying java.jpg..." jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:37:30.195 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] Sending upload request for 0" jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:37:30.199 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] xhr - server response received for 0" jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:37:30.199 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] responseText = {"error":"No files were uploaded.","uploadName":null}" jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:37:30.199 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] Received response status 200 with body: {"error":"No files were uploaded.","uploadName":null}" jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:37:30.200 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] Waiting 5 seconds before retrying java.jpg..."
```

For apache httpd:

```
"[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] Retrying java.jpg..." jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:36:55.356 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] Sending upload request for 0" jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:36:55.361 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] xhr - server response received for 0" jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:36:55.361 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] responseText = {"error":"Could not save uploaded file.The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered","uploadName":"java.jpg"}" jquery.fineuploader-4.3.1.min.js:16
18:36:55.361 "[Fine Uploader 4.3.1] Received response status 200 with body: {"error":"Could not save uploaded file.The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered","uploadName":"java.jpg"}"
```

The **request method**  is the same, no matter on what server I am running:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/webpage/html/php/fineuploader/endpoint.php
Request Method:     POST
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Request Headers 18:37:30.000
X-Requested-With:   XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Referer:    http://localhost:8000/webpage/html/index.html
Pragma: no-cache
Host:   localhost:8000
Content-Type:   multipart/form-data;     
Content-Length: 13274
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Response Headers Δ1ms
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.5.10
Host:   localhost:8000
Content-Type:   text/plain
Connection: close
```

My opinion is that the problem is with the servers.

**My code:**

my endpoint.php: https://gist.github.com/mbriskar/9512416

my handler.php: https://gist.github.com/mbriskar/9512432

Comment: You'll need to provide more information if you require assistance, such as your server code and console log messages.

Comment: Hi, thank you, the code is really only a copy of your tutorials. For the server code, I use https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php/traditional ,I have changed only the allowedExtension row in the endpoint.php. For the client code, I am using only the snippet from the tutorial with linking the endpoint urls to match the endpoint.php. The javascript and css are downloaded so there should not be a problem with it.

Comment: What messages are you seeing in the console?  Also, please provide the request headers/payloads according to your browser's dev tools.  The issue is likely either in your server code, or with your server's configuration.

Comment: @Matthew, that PHP server was not made with the intention of running based on the Getting Started guide. The guide has its own server in part 3. You'll have to modify some things (not much) to get it working with that PHP server most notably the endpoint value.

Comment: This is clearly a server error: `"Could not save uploaded file.The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered"` Occurring on [this line](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/traditional/handler.php#L179).

Comment: @Ray I added the information that you wanted. Hi Mark, thank you for the interest also. I know that it didn't fit 100% to my php, but I changed the endpoint paths and changed the accepted file-endings in the endpoint.php only so I would say I have 99% of the code from the tutorials/examples.

Comment: Please show all of your PHP code, there is likely some issue with your modifications

Comment: @Mark you are probably right, I just tried it whole on another server (httpd) so we will have more feedbacks. But I would like to know also if someone of you does know what happened in the built-in php server.

Comment: You'll need to look closely starting at this line: https://gist.github.com/mbriskar/9512432#file-handler-php-L165  Either `$target` is null, or the call to `move_uploaded_file` is failing.

Comment: I would like to mention that the error with the write privileges when runned with the httpd server is later than the error "No files were uploaded." so it means it is a server problem, because on httpd there is no such a problem but for the built-in php server, there is.

Comment: @Mathew , "the error with the write privileges" -- where is this. That's the 3rd unique error you've posted. It makes it difficult to diagnose what is actually going on. `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` is only set in PHP when a POST request is received, and you said that both "servers" are sending the same request method (which appears to be POST). You have created the proper directories, right?

Comment: I got it to work with httpd perfectly, selinux was blocking httpd from writing to the directory.

Comment: @Mathew Please post this as an answer, as it may help others in the future.

Comment: @Ray sure, it is just the problem with the permission denied. Still dont know what is happening with PHP built-in server. If I will have more time I will take a look at it and then write an answer summing it all. Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: thank you guys for the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem “No files were uploaded” occurred only for the php built-in web-server and after switching to httpd has never occurred again.

The writing problem with the httpd server was caused by the SELinux.